# Count sub-subelements with hql

Tags: hibernate, count, traversal

i want to get Elements and the amount of certain sub-subelements without actually loading them, i tried this:

```
f, count(f.themen.responses) FROM Forum f WHERE f.grouping=:group
```

but i get

```
node to traverse cannot be null!
```

how can i archieve something like that?

tanks

Comment: out of the 2 mappings, either **f.themen.responses** or **f.grouping** has null values?

Comment: no, the error occurs before querrying the db, it occurs when parsing the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get *node to traverse cannot be null!*, because you didn't specified SELECT in query. Next problem is that aggregate function (`COUNT`) is used in query, but `f` is not in `GROUP BY`.

Query where both of those problems are fixed is:

```
SELECT f, count(f.themen.responses) 
FROM Forum f WHERE f.grouping=:group
GROUP BY f
```